# How can I ensure certain items always display at the end of a list?

Tags: templating, forloop

I have a website where I want to show Power Coat (`-PC`) options *at the end of a list*. The data goes into Craft in an unpredictable order, from a third-party service, so I am responsible for organizing it in the front-end.

Is there a way I can split out or force the **-PC** items to always appear at the end of the list, in my template?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How would you like to identify that particular entry? If you're happy to hardcode its id, then I'd do it like this with the [filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html#filter) filter and the [without](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html#without) filter:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('products').all() %}
{% set pcEntry = allEntries|filter(item => item.id = 1234) %}
{% set entriesWithoutPC = allEntries|without(pcEntry) %}
```

You can now output those however/wherever you like, e.g.

```
<ul>
  {% for product in entriesWithoutPC %}
    <li>{{ product.title }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  <li>{{ pcEntry[0].title }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

James’s answer is correct, if there's only one list of items. I'm going to propose a derivative solution, in case you're dealing with an abstract set of elements (like a common pattern across many Products’ Variants).

```
{% set finishes = product.variants %}
{% set powderCoatedSuffix = 'PC' %}

<ul>
  {# Output the variants that *don't* end with `PC`: #}
  {% for variant in variants | filter(v => v.sku[-2:] != powderCoatedSuffix) %}
    <li>{{ variant.title }}: {{ variant.sku }}</li>
  {% endfor %}

  {# Then, output those that *do*: #}
  {% for variant in variants | filter(v => v.sku[-2:] == powderCoatedSuffix) %}
    <li>{{ variant.title }}: {{ variant.sku }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The only trickery here is the short syntax for the [`slice`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html) filter—in this case, taking the last two characters of the string.